# Create a global Rails method inside a module?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I need to create a method that can be used in any situation (MVC, testing etc). Instead of stuffing it in `environments.rb` id like to create a module and include it as a gem. What class do I need to extend in my gem in order to get Rails to recognize the methods in this module?

Update:

I'm looking for a solution that allows me to call my method without a module prefixed.

Comment: Sounds like you want a `Kernel` method? You can put it, for example, in `lib/core_ext/kernel.rb`, and require it from `config/boot.rb`.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

#### TLDR

You need to "extend" the `Kernel` module by including your methods into it with `include`.

#### Global methods

Generally a "global" method in Ruby means creating a method in `Kernel` or `Object`.  The method is then available to all (most) classes because they inherit from `Object` (which includes `Kernel`). Your method can be called without a prefix from most places because the implicit `self` in any given context will be an object that inherits from `Object` and therefore contains the method you defined.

One way to define such a method is just to place its definition in a file outside of any class or module:

```
def my_method
  # do fancy stuff
end
```

Of course, you have to make sure that file gets loaded (i.e. required) somewhere.

#### Global methods from a module

If you want your method to be organized within a module (which is a good idea), you need to include that module into `Kernel` like this:

```
module MySpecialMethods
  def my_method
    # do fancy stuff
  end
end

module Kernel
  private
  include MySpecialMethods # This is where the method gets added to Kernel
end
```

In Rails, I would put the `MySpecialMethods` module in `lib/`, add put the `Kernel` part inside an initializer file like `config/initializers/extend_kernel.rb`.  You also need to help Rails "find" your module in `lib/` by adding `config.autoload_paths += %W(#{config.root}/lib)` to application.rb

#### Consider avoiding global methods

It's worth nothing that there are very few situations where it's a good idea to extend `Kernel` in this way. It's possible (likely?) that for your situation it is *better* to put your methods in a module and explicitly call them with the module name like `MyModule.my_method`.

```
module MyModule
  def self.my_method
    # do fancy stuff here
  end
end
```

There are *many* places you could place this code.  In Rails, I'd recommend putting it in the `lib/` folder as above and then making sure Rails can find it by adding `config.autoload_paths += %W(#{config.root}/lib)` to application.rb

#### From a Gem

Creating a gem is beyond the scope of this question, but supposing you created a gem, typically the modules within that gem are available in your Rails app as long as you specify the gem in your Gemfile. This is because Rails apps by default call `Bundler.require`. As long as the gem follows proper naming conventions, the main gem file is required automatically, and the main gem file requires any other necessary files.

If you want to extend `Kernel` from a gem, just put the `Kernel` extension code (from above) inside a file that is required (directly or indirectly) when your gem is required.

#### Notes

1. Rails initializers only run once when you boot the Rails server, so changes to them are not autoloaded like many other pieces of Rails in development.
2. If you're tweaking Rails' `autoload_paths`, you might also want to tweak `eager_load_paths` (see [this blog post](http://blog.arkency.com/2014/11/dont-forget-about-eager-load-when-extending-autoload/))
3. There are *some* objects in Ruby that *do* *not* inherit from `Object` (e.g. [BasicObject](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/BasicObject.html)), so technically these "global" methods will not be available *everywhere*. That's not likely to cause problems for you.
4. Using `Bundler.require` in a Rails app is perhaps controversial (see [this blog post](http://myronmars.to/n/dev-blog/2012/12/5-reasons-to-avoid-bundler-require) for more information on that)

Comment: Thanks for your reply. So will this allow me to call `my_method` without needing to prefix an object (`foo.my_method`)?

Comment: In the example I provided, you would call it as `MyModule.my_method` from anywhere in your code --- tests, controllers, models, views, etc.

Comment: I see. I'm looking for a solution that allows me to call `my_method` without the module prefixed. Any ideas?

Comment: I have updated my answer now that I understand your question better. I also updated your question to clarify you intent.